# How to upload multiple files in JSF2 with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jsf-2

I need an example to upload multiple files with jquery plugin and to implement it with JSF 2 support all browsers. i saw many plugins but its implementation with php but i need with jsf.

I need to use jquery plugin instead of primefaces as it has problems in safari and IE.

Comment: Check out primefaces multiple file upload component http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf INMO its your best bet... (unless you got some restrictions and spare time...)